# Changing countdown's end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, countdown

I'm using this countdown library: https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/Countdown.js

Sometimes I need to change the counter's end value. What am I doing now is that I have a function that creates new countdown with a specific value. This solution is kinda buggy because sometimes the counter counts down both values (the old one and the new one).

Javascript isn't really my main language so I need help from you, how can I effectively change the countdown's value even when the previous countdown isn't over.

```
function updateTimer( d ) {
    return new Countdown({
        selector: '#timer',
        msgPattern: "{minutes}:{seconds}</b>",
        msgAfter: "00:00",
        dateEnd: new Date( d )
    });
}
```

This is the function I was writing about above. This is what the strings I'm passing to that function looks like "2015-06-25T15:35:12+02:00"

Comment: By Countdown end value you mean it shouldn't reach zero?!

Comment: No, I'm gettind new values from eventstream, It's okay if the countdown reach zero, but only if its supossed to.

Comment: Okay so you want to constantly reset the count down value whenever you have a new value?

Comment: Yes, I want to "destroy" the previous countdown and start a new one with the value I got from eventstream.

Comment: Can't you just change the dateEnd attribute of the Countdown object?

Comment: I tried that but got the same result as before, It's still buggy.